# datatables column search boxes not showing

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

Datatable used is version 1.10.12

I would assume following to work, but it does not. I mean everything else works except the search fields, they do not show up. JSON data is obtained from server to draw the table.

here is the HTML:

```
<span>
    <table name="item" id="item" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    </table>
</span>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //#################  initial table draw
    var oTable;     //global
    var rowIndexGlobal = 0;
    var colIndexGlobal = 0;

    $.getJSON( "item.pl?Action=getlist", function( data ) {
        var dataSet = [];
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        dataSet.push(val);
        });

        oTable = $('#item').DataTable({
            data: dataSet,          
            columns: [
                { title: "ID" },
                { title: "Item" },
                { title: "Inventory" },
                { title: "Price" },
                { title: "Sale" },
            ],
            "fnInitComplete": function() {
                $('#item tbody tr').each(function(){
                        $(this).find('td:eq(3)').attr('nowrap', 'nowrap');      //making text to NOT-wrap.
                });
                $("#datatables4_wrapper").css("width","100%");
                //this did not work so i have commented out
                /*var r = $('#item tfoot tr');
                r.find('th').each(function(){
                    $(this).css('padding', 8);
                });
                $('#item thead').append(r);
                $('#search_0').css('text-align', 'center');*/
            },
            "bAutoWidth": false
        });
        // Sort by columns 1 and 9 and redraw <- it works, but search does not....
        oTable
            .order( [ 1, 'asc' ], [ 9, 'asc' ] )
            .draw()
            .columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;
                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });
    });
});
```

I also want to have these search boxes under headers, as first row of the table....

this code comes from site, why does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the creation of the search boxes in your code

Please add the below lines before initializing the DataTable(`oTable = $('#item').DataTable({..`)

```
// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#item tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );
```

If you want the search boxes under the header just add the below `CSS`

```
tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/ehhfsrfq/

Comment: Thx for looking, there is major diff between this and my situation. in my HTML code there is no pre-existing table. Table is built on the fly with JSON data. I have already tried that code "before generating table", also in  "fnInitComplete routine", and also after table generated (drawn). It does not work.

Comment: Do you mean your `table` tag itself getting generated dynamically OR your data is coming dynamically and you are assigning it to table ?

Comment: If you can create `JSFiddle` of your problem, it will be helpful to tackle the problem.

Comment: sorry do not know how to create a fiddle. but i found a solution which almost works: 1. add table row using javascript to the ID. 2: include in DataTable code the search code. it now works, but now the tbale columns are fixed width and data in them wraps around....

Comment: $("#item").append('<tfoot><tr><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr></tfoot>');    //<th></th> pair should match no of columns in table.

Comment: then generate the table using the JSON data coming in from server. it creates footer,

Comment: Glad you found the solution. For wrapping problem you can apply the `no-wrap` CSS property to your table. Enjoy coding..